# python import multiple times

Tags: python, import, python-3.4

I suppose this is a general question so sorry if not posted in the right place.

Say for instance, I have a function `a` which imports `os`. If I was to call this function from another file multiple times I am assuming that the import would be done multiple times as well? Is there a way to only import the module if its not already present?

Basically, I have a class which calls multiple functions imported from various files, instead of importing the whole file I thought it would be easier to import just the function but now I am wondering if I am going to give myself headaches in the long run with excess imports.

Comment: The biggest question is why are you importing inside the function and not at the top of the file? There's almost no reason to do that and doing so is a code smell.

Comment: Python cache imported modules and doesn't import them twice.

Comment: i was importing just a function from the module, so to avoid errors i included the imports in the function, im assuming i should import the whole file and just call the function as normal?

Comment: Importing "just a function" from a module still executes all the module's code if the module hasn't previously been loaded. You don't need to move imports into the function to guarantee they'll happen.

Comment: Actually, if your question was the opposite, then you'd have to do some special case handling with *reload(os)* to force it to be imported again.  But as it is and as other answers state, you're already covered.  As far as @Two-BitAlchemist 's remark goes, he's correct as well.  Though sometimes doing so avoid issues with circular module references (still a code smell).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As [described](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem) in the python documentation, when python see some import statement it does the following things:

- checks some global table if the module is already imported

  - if the module is not there, python imports it, creates a module object and puts the newly created module object in the global table
  - if the module is there, python just gets module object
- when python has the module object, it binds it to the name you chose

  - if it was `import foo`, the name for the module `foo` will be `foo`
  - if it was `import foo as bar`, the name for the module `foo` will be `bar`
  - if it was `from foo import bar as baz`, python finds the function (or whatever) `bar` in module `foo` and will bind this function to the name `baz`

So each module is imported only one time.

To better understand import mechanics, I would suggest creating a toy example.

File `module.py`:

```
print("import is in progress")

def foo():
    pass
```

File `main.py`:

```
def foo():
    print("before importing module")
    import module
    module.foo()
    print("after importing module")
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    foo()
```

Put the above files in the same directory. When `module.py` is being imported, it prints `import is in progress`. When you launch `main.py`, it will try to import `module` several times but the output will be:

```
before importing module
import is in progress
after importing module
before importing module
after importing module
```

So import really happens only once. You can adjust this toy example to check cases that are interesting to you.

Comment: Great, very clear. Just one more thing need to be carefule. If later you import module to a with **as** like `from module import foo as new_name`, the previous module name would be coverd shows `global name 'module' is not defined`

Comment: Same mechanism for JavaScript.