# Python program importing itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, circular-dependency

I made a file named `challenge.py` with this code in it:

```
import challenge

def main():
     print('Circular much...')

challenge.main()
```

From this I was expecting python to raise an error due to the circular import of importing the file which is running but I found that on python 3.7 & 3.8 this file runs and prints out `Circular much...` twice. I would understand once as that would mean that the rest of the file when it is importing itself isn't running and I would understand a recursion error as it ran challenge.main() infinitely down the stack but I don't understand why it prints it twice and stops?

Comment: `import challenge` `print("Circular much...")` is a more minimal example.

Comment: @alaniwi It does result in the same thing and I also don't understand why that happens however that isn't quite what is happening here because it is running the `main()` from the challenge.py it is importing and not itself

Comment: Okay I see that there is more to it, and I added an additional answer - there isn't any distinction between "itself" and "the challenge.py it is importing", because after the `import` statement `challenge` will point back at the same module as part of the behaviour that prevents the same thing being imported more than once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tracing this through:

```
import challenge
```

Ok, we'll `import` challenge.py. Here we go...

- ```
  import challenge
  ```

  We're already importing challenge.py, so [we won't do it again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37077911/10077).

  ```
  def main():
       print('Circular much...')
  ```

  Defined the function `main()` in the namespace `challenge`. Cool.

  ```
  challenge.main()
  ```

  Now *call* the function `main()` in the namespace `challenge`. That prints **Circular much...**. There's your first print.

Now we're back in the main module again.

```
def main():
     print('Circular much...')
```

This defines the function `main()` in the global namespace (which never gets called).

```
challenge.main()
```

This calls the function `main()` in the namespace `challenge`, again printing **Circular much...**.

And we're done. Two prints of your message.

Answer (score 2):

It may be instructive to look at `sys.modules`.

For example:

```
import sys

def check_modules():
     print("seeing what we have...")
     if "challenge" in sys.modules:

          module = sys.modules["challenge"]
          
          print(f"sys.modules contains {module.__file__}")
          
          if hasattr(module, "challenge"):
               print("... and it contains the variable 'challenge'")
               if module is module.challenge:
                    print("... pointing back at itself")
                    
          if hasattr(module, "main"):
               print("... and it contains the variable 'main'")
               
     print()

print("Before import:")
check_modules()

import challenge

print("After import:")
check_modules()

def main():
     print('Circular much...')

print("After declaring 'main':")
check_modules()
     
challenge.main()
```

gives:

```
Before import:
seeing what we have...

Before import:
seeing what we have...
sys.modules contains /tmp/challenge.py

After import:
seeing what we have...
sys.modules contains /tmp/challenge.py
... and it contains the variable 'challenge'
... pointing back at itself

After declaring 'main':
seeing what we have...
sys.modules contains /tmp/challenge.py
... and it contains the variable 'challenge'
... pointing back at itself
... and it contains the variable 'main'

Circular much...
After import:
seeing what we have...
sys.modules contains /tmp/challenge.py
... and it contains the variable 'challenge'
... pointing back at itself
... and it contains the variable 'main'

After declaring 'main':
seeing what we have...
sys.modules contains /tmp/challenge.py
... and it contains the variable 'challenge'
... pointing back at itself
... and it contains the variable 'main'

Circular much...
```

As you can see, the module gets added to `sys.modules` at the *start* of the import, before the actual code in the module being imported is run.  If the `import` statement is reached when the module file is present in `sys.modules`, then this is sufficient to prevent it being imported again, which is why there is only a single level of recursion.

Once the import is finished, the result of the import (a module object) is assigned to the variable `challenge`, and the `if module is module.challenge` test in the code confirms that it is a reference to the same module as the one in which the name is created (as importing a module already imported simply reuses the same module object already created).

Now as regards the question of how the call to `challenge.main` works: precisely because `challenge` is simply a reference to the current module, this means that when the function definition is executed, thereby creating the name `main` inside the current module object, the same function object to which it points can equally be accessed as `challenge.main` instead of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting python to raise an error due to the circular import of
> importing the file which is running

Now that folks have explained why it *didn't* work, let's consider what it takes to *make* it work.  Perhaps:

```
from sys import argv

print('Circular much...')

exec(open(argv[0]).read())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 challenge.py
Circular much...
Circular much...
Circular much...
Circular much...
Circular much...
... # 489 more recursions later
Circular much...
Circular much...
Circular much...
Circular much...
Circular much...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "challenge.py", line 5, in <module>
    exec(open(argv[0]).read())
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  [Previous line repeated 494 more times]
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
%
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only running twice: once because the file was ran and again because the file is imported. The second time the line 'import challenge' is read, it does not recursively import forever because it was already imported into this namespace, which prevents it from importing a second time. Just like how importing a module twice in the same script will only import the module once.