# Numpy issues needed assistance

Tags: python, numpy

Confused what I do wrong any help helps
I trying to understand numpy and learn it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqPAw.png

```
import numpy as np

jeff_salary = [3300,2700,9000,2900]

base_salary = np.array([jeff_salary])
print(base_salary)
```

Comment: Please, add code in code blocks, not as an image

Comment: In addition to what Vladimir mentioned, please mention what is the issue, what is the current behavior and what is the the expected behavior.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Your file has a name `numpy.py`.

The line `import numpy as np` doesn't import numpy. Instead - [it imports itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62665924/14627505)! (your own script). And of course, your module doesn't have an attribute `array`.

Rename your script, for example to: `learning_numpy.py`, and it should work.

You had a hint in the error message:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array' (most likely due to a circular import).