# Cannot create a defined function that import all libraries

Tags: python

Here's my defined function which purposely to import my libraries

```
def all_package():
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
all_package()

a = pd.Dataframe([1,2,3])
```

```
pd is not existed
```

So, my question is how can I fix my function to make it able to import all libraries

Comment: Well… `global`…?!

Comment: Why do you want to use a function for this? Why not just do your imports at the top of the file, like how it's normally done?

Comment: It could be possible with `global` as suggested by @deceze, but it would lead to *not pythonic* code. If you really need that, add comments explaining the rationale for future readers/maintainers.

Comment: Are you really just asking why this happens, or do you want to know how to fix it?

Comment: The discussion in [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067414/python-import-multiple-times#comment61701388_37067414) might interest you as well, @Wallika

Answer (score 2):

The most clean way to standardize imports is to make a new file, maybe `standard_imports.py` containing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then, in your main script, you can easily import everything using:

```
from standard_imports import *
```

---

Some other less neat options:

```
def all_package():
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    return np, pd, plt
np, pd, plt = all_package()
```

This still makes a function without side side effects in the global scope, but assuming the goal is to use this function in many modules, means adding a package would involve changing every module.

The simplest way is to use the `global` keyword, but it is generally bad practice to change the global scope in a function. The `global` keyword is considered a code smell usually:

```
def all_package():
    global np, pd, plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

all_package()
```

Comment: lol. That still doesn't answer the OP's question. They didn't ask for solution, they asked the reason.

Comment: @BlackThunder I think the reason is implicitly in that answer that the created "variable" for the imported package name is only in scope inside that function

Comment: @lucidbrot I know that. I am talking about the answer mousetail has posted.