# Running a python script inside a for loop of another python script

Tags: python, for-loop, python-import

I want to run a python script inside another script's for-loop every loop.
The below code works but only for the first loop ("run_this_script.py" only executes when i=1). How can I get it to run every iteration?

```
for i in range (1,10)
   import run_this_script.py
```

Comment: you are either going to have to use a subprocess, or you will need to edit the script to encapsulate the logic into a function

Comment: Guess you could run it with `os.system('path-to-python-file')`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067414/python-import-multiple-times

Comment: I assume you meant `import run_this_script` (no .py). Is this your own script you are trying to run? You could potentially put whatever this script does into a function and call that repeatedly.

Comment: Correct, yes no ".py" at the end, sorry. When I try os.system("path") it opens the file in VSC but doesn't run (I'm using Spyder IDE)

Comment: execfile("path") seems to work, although is weird because the code analysis shows a red cross icon at the line number and says "Undefined name 'execfile'" but it runs..

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments](//stackoverflow.com/q/3781851/90527)", "[What is the best way to call a script from another script?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1186789/90527)"

Comment: As mentioned in at [least one answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/1186826/90527), you should consider instead defining a function (or class) in the other script that is then called from the loop body (rather than launching a whole new process).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

for i in range(1, 10):
   print(f'{i}. ')
   os.system('python run_this_script.py')
```

Comment: This works, although I have some print functions in the script being called I'd like to see that won't appear in the Spider console since os.system runs in the background. If I use functions/subprocess will this also be true?