# Change of a global variable gets lost when importing the enclosing namespace

Tags: python, import, scope, namespaces, global-variables

I was playing with scopes and namespaces and I found a weird behaviour which I'm not sure how to explain. Say we have a file called **new_script.py** with inside

```
a = 0

def func():
    import new_script #import itself
    new_script.a += 1
    print(new_script.a)

func()
print(a)
```

when executing it prints

```
1 
1 
2 
0
```

I didn't expect the last print of the number `0`. From what I understand, it prints the first two `1` executing the self-import statement incrementing the global `a`, then it prints `2` because it increments again the global `a` from inside the function, but then why the last print is `0` instead of `2`?

Comment: The last `0` comes from the last time that `print(a)` runs. This is because the `a` in `__main__` is never incremented.

Comment: What would be the use case of such a script ?

Comment: @dragonfire_007 it's not the use of the script itself. It's understanding how the language works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this has lead down a very interesting rabit hole. So thanks you for that.

Here are the key points:

- Imports will not recurse. If it's imported once, it will execute the module level code, but it will not execute again if it's imported again. Hence you only see 4 values.
- Imports are [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). If you try this code:

```
# singleton_test.py
import singleton_test

def func():
    import singleton_test #import itself
    print(singleton_test.singleton_test == singleton_test)

func()
```

It will print:

```
True
True
```

- The imported singleton version of a module is different from the original ran version of the module

With this in mind, we can explore your code, by enriching it with a few more comments, particularly using `__name__` which contains the name of the current module, which will be `__main__` if the current module is what was ran originally:

```py
a = 0

print("start", __name__)

def func():
    print("Do import", __name__)
    import new_script #import itself
    new_script.a += 1
    print(new_script.a, "func", __name__)

func()
print(a, "outr", __name__)
```

This will print

```
start __main__
Do import __main__
start new_script
Do import new_script
1 func new_script
1 outr new_script
2 func __main__
0 outr __main__
```

This shows you quite well, given that the imported module is a singleton (but not the module that was ran), that you

- first print 1 in the function after you incremented value inside the function inside the module
- then you print 1 at the end of the imported module
- then you print 2 after incrementing the value on the singleton on the original run code
- then finally you print 0 for the unchanged outer module that you originally ran, but have not touched.

Comment: thank for your explaination! the key point I think is that importing a module creates a different namespace from the original one! I have just one question, could you specify a bit better what you mean by singleton?

Comment: Maybe do you mean that importing it in two different scopes doesn't make them different?

Comment: @Tortar By Singleton I refer to the common [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) where you only have one instance of an entity in your codebase

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: you have two different variables `__main__.a` and `new_script.a`. You only change `new_script.a`.

To trace it through:

```
a = 0
```

defines a variable `a` in `__main__` module.

```
def func(): ...
```

defines a function `func` in `__main__` module.

```
func()
```

calls this function in `__main__` module. In function:

```
import new_script
```

imports `new_script` module in which:

```
a = 0
def func(): ...
```

defines `a` and `func` in `new_script` module (`new_script.a` and `new_script.func`)

```
func()
```

calls `func` from `new_script` module. In function:

```
import new_script
```

well, we have it imported already so [we don't import it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067414/python-import-multiple-times/37077911#37077911)

```
new_script.a += 1
print(new_script.a)
```

increment `new_script.a` and print it (our first `1`). Then

```
print(a)
```

printing `a` (a.k.a `new_script.a`) from `new_script` module (our second `1`)

`new_script` is finished.
Back to execution in the `__main__`:

```
new_script.a += 1
print(new_script.a)
```

incrementing `new_script.a` second time and printing it (our `2`).

Finally:

```
print(a)
```

printing `a` (a.k.a. `__main__.a`) that has never been changed (so `0`)