# Why does unittest's `mock.patch.start` re-run the function in which the patcher is started?

Tags: python, python-unittest, patch, monkeypatching, python-unittest.mock

Let's say we have two files:

**to_patch.py**

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

def patch_a_function():
    print("Patching!")
    patcher = patch("to_be_patched.function")
    patcher.start()
    print("Done patching!")
```

**to_be_patched.py**

```py
from to_patch import patch_a_function

def function():
    pass

patch_a_function()
function()
```

And we run `python -m to_be_patched`. This will output:

```
Patching!
Patching!
```

1. Why isn't `Done patching!` ever printed?
2. Why is `Patching!` printed twice?

I've narrowed the answer to (2) down; the call to `patch.start` seems to trigger `patch_a_function` again. I suspect this is because it's imported in `to_be_patched.py`, but am not sure why the function itself would run for a second time. Similarly, I'm not sure why the `Done patching!` line is not reached in either of the calls to `patch_a_function`. `patcher.start()` can't be blocking, because the program exits nicely instead of hanging there... right?

**Edit:** Huh. It looks like no one can reproduce `Done patching!` *not* being printed (which was honestly the main difficulty)—so I guess that's just a my-side problem

Comment: The first "Patching" is printed by calling patch_a_function in the `to_be_patched` module. The second "Patching" is printed by calling  ` patch("to_be_patched.function")` in the `to_patch` module. Also, I get  "Done patching!" printed on python `3.10.0`. What version are you running this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why isn't `Done patching!` ever printed?

Can not reproduce.

```
$ python -m to_be_patched
Patching!
Patching!
Done patching!
Done patching!
```

> 2. Why is `Patching!` printed twice?

Your module gets imported twice. If you add `print(__name__)` into the file `to_be_patched.py` it will be clear:

```
from to_patch import patch_a_function

print(f"{__name__=}")

def function():
    pass

patch_a_function()
function()  # note: this line doesn't actually do anything, and could be commented out
```

Result:

```
$ python -m to_be_patched
__name__='__main__'
Patching!
__name__='to_be_patched'
Patching!
Done patching!
Done patching!
```

When you use `python -m to_be_patched` your module `to_be_patched` will be loaded as [top-level code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#what-is-the-top-level-code-environment), i.e. the module `__name__` will be `"__main__"`.

When `mock.patch` is used, mock will [first import the patch target](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4426e8d001cfb4590911e2e7de6963e12529faf/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1754-L1756). When given a patch target as a string like `"to_be_patched.function"` mock will use `importlib`, via [`pkgutil.resolve_name`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4426e8d001cfb4590911e2e7de6963e12529faf/Lib/pkgutil.py#L458), to find the correct namespace in which to patch. This method loads the target module with `__name__` as `"to_be_patched"`, it's not the top-level code environment. Although it's the same underlying .py file being loaded, there is a cache miss in `sys.modules`, because of the name mismatch: `"__main__" != "to_be_patched"`.

The function `patch_a_function` now has dual identities and exists in the module `__main__` as well as the module `to_be_patched`, so what you're seeing is each one getting called. The first call triggers the second call, by the double-import mechanism described.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that occurs here is not related to `patcher.start()`, but due to circular imports and calling `patch_a_function` from the top level of a script.

When you run `to_be_patched` it calls `patch_a_function`.

Now in `patch_a_function`'s `patcher = patch("to_be_patched.function")` needs to imports `to_be_patched` and when it's called it calls `patch_a_function` again.

This time when `patch("to_be_patched.function")` is called, it doesn't reimport the `to_be_patched` because it was already imported, so from this point script continues as expected.

You could describe steps as:

```
 1. CALL patch_a_function
 2. print("Patching!")
 3. CALL `patch("to_be_patched.function")`
 4. `patch` CALLS __import__ of `to_be_patched`
 5. `to_be_patched` is not imported yet so import module
 6. During the import CALL patch_a_function
 7. print("Patching!")
 8. CALL `patch("to_be_patched.function")`
 9. `patch` CALLS __import__ of `to_be_patched`
 10. `to_be_patched` is already imported
 11. Finish the rest of second time called 
 12. CALL patcher.start()
 13. print("Done patching!")
 14. CALL function() (still it is done since we import the module) 
 15. CALL patcher.start()
 16. print("Done patching!")
 17. CALL function()
```

If you want to resolve the problem in `to_be_patched` call functions in `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement:

```
from to_patch import patch_a_function

def function():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    patch_a_function()
    function()
```

Here's more info about top-level code environment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Since we're stuck in an import loop, why doesn't it print `Patching!` infinitely?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I'm sorry, my bad. Using the word `loop` does not perfectly describe the situation here. `patch` will import once `to_be_patched`, during the import `patch_a_function` will be called again. Then `patch` will import again `to_be_patched` but since it was already imported it will return the module that it imported previously (what happens during importing multiple times same module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067414/python-import-multiple-times)

I will edit answer and remove the misleading `loop`

Comment: I couldn't though recreate a situation where `Done patching!` is not being printed.